# cakephp 2 fields linked to same table

Tags: mysql, cakephp, relationship

I have 2 3 tables

```
 USERS [id, name, fname, username, password, email, role]
 STUDENTS[id, class]
 FEES [id, user_id, month,amount, user_id]
```

First: I want to link users and students by user.id=student.id
it can be linked by adding user_id field in students but can it be done like this
and is it good using cakephp

second: fees table has 2 times user_id, one for student and second for admin
as students and admins are getting log in so I kept both of them in same USERS table
I am confused how to query
some times I am using containable 
some time I query separately for fee and then student and then user as admin even in some page I just get stuck

please help where can I make changes to run smoothly with recommended approach

Answer (score 0):

1: Use cakephp's [model relations](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html) to make this, but read the docs carefully because it might be a little tricky to get working the first time.

2: Does the entries on FEES have to have a student user AND a admin in every entry? If they do so rename the user_id corresponding to de admin to admin_id or something different.

Now if you're saying that a FEES entry MIGHT be a student or a admin, that are both users, so just have one user_id and then check it againts the role on the USERS table to see if it is a admin.